# SSL Certificate - nGinx - error 404

Tags: ssl, nginx

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-14-04) to generate a SSL certificate for my server but I'm getting this error.

> Failed authorization procedure. example.com (http-01): urn:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient authorization :: Invalid response from http://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/OdiQ9qPI7vwc-KVBOwc6BQulaN1827zzfx2ipqznmNM: "
>   404 Not Found

#### nGinx

```
location ^~ /.well-known/ {
                allow all;
                root /var/www/laravel;
        }
```

`nginx-t` does not return any error.
If I create a folder `test` and a file `text.txt` I'm able to access it with `http://example.com/.well-known/test/text.txt`. I tried removing the folder `well-know`, set `chmod 0777` nothing is working...

#### Questions

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked

```
location ~ /.well-know/acme-challenge {
        allow all;
        root /var/www/laravel;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

try to change the config block to

```
location ~ .well-known/ {
         allow all;
         root /var/www/laravel;
}
```